# Store and retrieve value on Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to save a String value on Android and have access to this String every time the application starts.

For instance the String value will have the user's name which he has created on his own. And after restarting the app he would have this name already on the top. Like a cookie or something. How to save such file on android memory ?

Can someone guide me?

I used:

```
public class Login extends Activity
{
String user = null;

public String saveUserOnAndroid()
{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);

    String savedUser = myPrefs.getString("user", null);

    if(savedUser == null)
    {
        user = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String hashedUser = md5(user);
        SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();

        myPrefsEditor.putString("user", hashedUser);
        myPrefsEditor.commit();

        return hashedUser;
    }   
    else
        return savedUser;
}
```

and it seems not to work well.

Comment: Before posting such a question check to make sure that it wasn't asked already.

Comment: You need to be more specific on what you want. WHY is not "not working well for you? We need more information.

Comment: It was me who posted same wuestion but couldnt paste code there. Thanks for vote.

Comment: there is none error shown but the program always create new String like there is none saved before.

Comment: shall i add some permission into Manifest ?

Comment: what is the current behavior?

Comment: Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and try again:

Comment: the getApplicationContext() is uneeded for your example. You should be able to remove that method call and just leave it with getSharedPreferences(). using getApplicationContext() like this can lead to memory leaks, if you need a context it is better to use YourActivity.this. So for your case it would be Login.this

Comment: OK, I did removed it and the it behave like before. It creates new String and not retriving old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you didn't mention you're calling the `saveUserOnAndroid()` method from **another** class. In this case:

```
public String saveUserOnAndroid(Context c) {
  SharedPreferences myPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
  String savedUser = myPrefs.getString("user", null);

  if(savedUser == null) {
    user = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String hashedUser = md5(user);
    SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();

    myPrefsEditor.putString("user", hashedUser);
    myPrefsEditor.commit();

    return hashedUser;
  } else {
    return savedUser;
  }
}
```

And when calling this method, don't forget to supply it the required `Context` and you should be okay.

Comment: Yes sure, just did it. I do not have onCreate() method cuz I call this method saveUserOnAndroid() from another class, can it be a cause?

Comment: This ideally shouldn't make a difference. An Activity extends Context. Which is why it has those methods and EVERYTHING involved with context

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). I recommend using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: I do use SharedPreferences but i cannot retrive saved info.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it:

```
public static final String mypref="mypref";
public static String Username="";

@Override
public void OnCreate(Bundle ic){
super.OnCreate(ic);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
SharedPreference sh = getSharedPreference(mypref, 0);
Username = sh.getString("User", Username);
}

public void onPause(){
super.onPause();
SharedPreference sh = getSharedPreference(mypref, 0);
SharedPreference.Editor editor = sh.edit();
editor.putString("User", Username);
}
```

Comment: gonna try this solution onPause is called after closing the api ?

Comment: yes go to this link :http://cse.spsu.edu/jpreston/CGDD4203/images/application_lifecycle_android.jpg